# OnClickListener listener is not working on frame layout

Tags: android

I have an activity containing frame layout for fragment transition. Frame layout is loading a fragment and now I want to set click listener on frame layout. But click listener is working properly.

here is the layout that contains frame layout for fragments

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".FragmentActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_balance"
android:id="@+id/layout">

<FrameLayout
    android:name="com.dd.cotech.Fragments.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentWindow"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
```

here is the listener coding

```
findViewById(R.id.fragmentWindow).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "I am click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem

Comment: But click listener is working properly - so what is the problem?

Comment: sorry for typo..click listener is not working at all.It is not catching click event.

Comment: Explanation: I have an activity which has frame layout for loading fragments.When fragment gets loaded I want frame layout (that contains loaded fragment) to be clickable.In my case when I have set click listener on frame layout but it is not catching event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your are doing wrong the declaration of the button.

Try this example:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

Comment: I dont want to set listener on button but on frame layout.

Comment: hmmm, ok, Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977873/framelayout-click-event-is-not-firing Is really similar than your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
public class FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, OnTouchListener {

    private FrameLayout mFrame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentWindow);
        mFrame.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

        if(mFrame == v) {

           Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "I am click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Frame layout is not catching touch event

Answer (score 0):

first implement `OnClickListener` like

```
public class Avtivity_Name extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
```

then getview inside `OnCreateView` like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
 FrameLayout   layout = (FrameLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.fragmentWindow);
    layout.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootview;
}
```

and create `onClick` out side from onCreateView

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "I am click listner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you have too nested views.

for example

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    
                   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                       <FrameLayout
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `clickable` attribute like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:name="com.dd.cotech.Fragments.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentWindow"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

Comment: Does it make any sense? i mean I want my frame layout to be clickable an d you are recommending to make it clickable false?

Comment: Just make it true/false depending on your needs

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:clickable="true"` in FrameLayout tag.

If it doesn't work once try this line of code in base layout tag of fragment_home xml

Hope this will help you.