# Android frame layout click listener not working

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I've got a `FrameLayout` with two nested `LinearLayout`s. I want an `onClickListener()` for `FrameLayout`. After a search I got a solution `clickable="false"`.

This is my Layout file:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flOuter"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/half_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/flAddIdProof"
        android:background="@drawable/add_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:clickable="false"
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_button_border"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/llLinear"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:enabled="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/half_margin"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_devices_black_24dp"
            android:hint="Identity Proof"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:enabled="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_border_color_black_24dp"
            android:hint="Identity Number"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/half_margin"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my click listener:

```
flOuter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(DeviceInMeeting.this, "detect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I don't know how to debug for onClick listeners, `clickable="false"` is not working in my case.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37698640/1531971

Answer (score 8):

Try implementing `android:clickable="true"` in Following code snippet for `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout    
   android:id="@+id/flOuter"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:foreground="attr/selectableItemBackground"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/half_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_margin"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

and adding `android:clickable="false"` in other nested layout.

```
<LinearLayout    
   android:id="@+id/flOuter"
   android:clickable="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using it wrong. Try using:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flOuter"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/half_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    // Other layouts there

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: but i want clickable frame layout, not linear layout

Comment: You have used match_parent on both width and height of Inner LinearLayout. So it is covering the whole FrameLayout, hence the click is not working. Got my point ??

Comment: if i use `textView` instead of `edittext` then it working...not getting exact  solution

Answer (score 0):

For fields you don't want to be clicked add `clickable=false` to them.
And for fields for which you wan't click event add `clickable=true` for them.

One thing to remember here is that if your child elements contain some clickable elements like buttons and edittexts and then you want to get click event on parent layout then add clickable false to the child and true to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `OnTouchListener` instead onClickListener. In `onTouch` method you can decide if touch event is pass to children (by returning false)  or consume event.

On your case you should do your logic and return true.