# Click event not working inside frame layout

Tags: android, click

```
public class GameView extends AppCompatActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.back_btn_game_view)
    Button backBtnGameView;

    public static Context context;
    public static TextView matchNameView;
    public static String currentState = "";
    private AssetsPropertyReader assetsPropertyReader;
    private Properties skorkastProperties;
    private String skorkastMgntURL;
    public static Socket mSocket;
    private String skorkastSocketURL;
    public static boolean userConnected;
    public HashMap<String, Variables> variableHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    public static TextView timer;


    public static long millisInFuture = 0;
    public static long countDownInterval = 1000;
    public static CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    public static long timeRemaining = 0;
    public static boolean isPaused = false;
    public static boolean isCanceled = false;
    public static String timeLeft = "", gameStatus = "";
    public static int periodCount = 0;
    public static int[] periodArray = new int[3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_view);
        butterknife.inject(this);
        matchNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.match_name);
        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        context = GameView.this;
        assetsPropertyReader = new AssetsPropertyReader(context);
        skorkastProperties = assetsPropertyReader.getProperties("skorkast.properties");
        skorkastMgntURL = skorkastProperties.getProperty("SKORKAST_MGNT_URL");
        skorkastSocketURL = skorkastProperties.getProperty("SKORKAST_SOCKET_URL");
        userConnected = false;

        String matchname = getIntent().getStringExtra("matchname");
        matchNameView.setText(matchname);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
        }

        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(skorkastSocketURL);
            mSocket.connect();

            JSONObject joinObj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                joinObj.put("name", "scorer");
                joinObj.put("match", matchname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (!GameView.userConnected) {
                GameView.mSocket.emit("join", joinObj, new Ack() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        GameView.userConnected = true;
                        Log.i("TAG", "connected");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "already connected");
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "error connect socket " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "error connect socket " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Data.changeMode(2);
        Data.changeState(3, 4);


        //when the user click back button, it need to set the initiate normal play as state--> need to remove

        if (Data.currentState.getName().equals("initiate_normal_play")) {
            if (Data.currentState.getCurrentView().getOrientation().equalsIgnoreCase("vertical")) {
                VerticalFragment vFragment = new VerticalFragment();
                vFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, vFragment).commit();
            } else {
                HorizontalFragment hFragment = new HorizontalFragment();
                hFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, hFragment).commit();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        SystemUiHelper uiHelper = new SystemUiHelper(this, SystemUiHelper.LEVEL_IMMERSIVE, flags);
        uiHelper.hide();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.i("TAG", "Fragment stack count :: " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {

            if (GameView.mSocket != null && GameView.mSocket.connected()) {
                GameView.mSocket.emit("userdisconnect");
            }
            this.finish();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }


    }
@OnClick(R.id.back_btn_game_view)
            public void onViewClicked () {
                Toast.makeText(this, "working finally",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

**XML file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/icehockey_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<FrameLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_btn_game_view"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/match_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Match Name"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="02:00"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have `Fragment` inside the `Activity` layout. I have created `click` event of a back `Button` in an `Activity` layout. When I click the back `Button` from `Fragment`, there no responses at all. 
  But I tried to move the `Button` outside `frame layout` within `LinearLayout` , it working, I don't understand why it is not working properly inside the frame layout. Please help me fix this.

`**Note**` : I trying the click to work inside the fragment by inflating a layout.

Comment: why are you setting  src in button??

Comment: sorry for that. Actually I am using Imagebutton here. I was also testing for other view if it works or not.

Comment: yes try to use ImageButton instead of button.

Comment: I did not do any thing .And set `onclicklistener` in my code .And it worked .So show your java code for your click event .

Comment: `@OnClick(R.id.back_btn_game_view)
    public void onViewClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "working finally", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`

Comment: see this answer, it may help you and fix your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69229755/6884103

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've set `android:clickable="true"` to parent `RelativeLayout`. So `RelativeLayout` is stealing its click event. Try removing it, to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove this line from your `RelativeLayout`.

```
...
<FrameLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:clickable="true" // Remove this line
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this in your `RelativeLayout` `LinearLayout`and `FrameLayout` .And try it .

```
android:clickable="true"
```

**Edit**

I test your code .And it worked .You can try this in your code .

```
findViewById(R.id.back_btn_game_view).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(YouActivity.this, "back_btn_game_view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
findViewById(R.id.fragment_container).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(YouActivity.this, "fragment_container", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

**Edit**

Your `onViewClicked` is in the `onBackPressed` method .So move it outside .

```
@OnClick(R.id.back_btn_game_view)
public void onViewClicked() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "working finally", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Click event not working in any case, you presented above. I tried to step by step removing too. It still not working.

Comment: You can remove your click  event code .And try mine in your code .I thought the problem is in here .

Comment: You can check it again.@opalfire

Comment: Tried your code too.. did not work. I will check it out tomorrow again and post original answer if found any.

Comment: Today i found two problems, we can't work with two `framelayout(root)` working together inside one layout for an click event .and `framelayout(@id/fragment_container)` is bieng used by fragment. I think these may be the problem. Can you help a bit on how to resolve these.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
I put your button after both textView inside frameLayout. 
Hope it will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/icehockey_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/match_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Match Name"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="02:00"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

          <Button
                android:id="@+id/back_btn_game_view"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back_button" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: ,Actual thing is i need back button work not place button somewhere else. Anyhow it didn't work.